# I get different random values for the same file

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to store photo in DB, and I use the below way to generate a random file name and store it in the DB.

```
 $path = $request->file('profile_photo')->store('public/profiles');
        $profile = ltrim($path,"public/profiles/");
```

However, **sometimes** I get different values in 
**DB**

[image: https://i.imgur.com/r8WAuHl.png]

and in **my folder**

[image]

I am using laravel 6.

Comment: If you wanna prevent duplicate name, you can use current timestamp and concatenate it with real filename. Timestamp_realfilename.extension

Comment: @MiladTeimouri The `store()` function already generates a filename with very, very low chances of a collision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ltrim()`, `rtrim()`, `trim()` remove by character mask, not full string.

```
$profile = ltrim($path,"public/profiles/");
```

It means remove all "p", "u", "b", "l", "i", "c", "/", etc. from the left side of `$path`.

If you want to get filename without path, you could use `basename()` function.

```
$profile = basename($path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright take a look at this `src/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.php`

```
/**
 * Store the uploaded file on a filesystem disk.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  array|string  $options
 * @return string|false
 */
public function store($path, $options = [])
{
    return $this->storeAs($path, $this->hashName(), $this->parseOptions($options));
}
/**
 * Store the uploaded file on a filesystem disk.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  array|string  $options
 * @return string|false
 */
public function storeAs($path, $name, $options = [])
{
    $options = $this->parseOptions($options);

    $disk = Arr::pull($options, 'disk');

    return Container::getInstance()->make(FilesystemFactory::class)->disk($disk)->putFileAs(
        $path, $this, $name, $options
    );
}
```

You can do this to get ride of the collision and confusion

```
// cache the file
$file = $request->file('profile_photo');

// generate a new filename. getClientOriginalExtension() for the file extension
$filename = 'profile-photo-' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

// save to public/photos as the new $filename
$path = $file->store('public/photos', $filename);

dd($path); // Check if you get the correct file path or not
```